# How can I make $_SESSIONs more secure?

Tags: php, security, session

It seems that the most popular school of thought is to randomly generate session IDs, to regenerate the session ID when the user logs in and to periodically regenerate the session ID for existing users while they're logged in, just for extra security.

I'm using an alternate solution, but I'm not a seasoned PHP pro and I'm concerned there's a glaring security hole (or two... or more) that I might be missing.

If you could have a look at the following and tell me how it might be compromised, I'd appreciate it.

The script creates a session ID that's tied to the user's machine and remains the same throughout. I was thinking of including the current date in the hash, but our night shift workers would then get logged out at midnight. Not that I'd be around to hear their complaining ;)

I do realise that using IP address opens it up to abuse if two users with the same OS and browser are sitting in a coffee shop, using the free WiFi, but this is for an internal MIS, so each user will have their own static IP address. If they decide later to make it accessible from the web I'm in trouble! But that wasn't part of the spec :)

```
// Set the session ID
$session_hash = md5( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] );
// Compare against session ID received from user
if ( session_id() != $session_hash )
{
    session_destroy();
    unset ( $_SESSION );
    session_id( $session_hash );
    session_start();
}
else
{
    // Attempt to load user details from database if $_SESSION['user_ID'] is set.
}
```

All constructive comments welcomed and appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't bother trying to create your own session IDs. Your method is particularly weak as many people will share the same remote host, user agent and remote address in the case of proxy servers.

Use PHP's built-in sessions unless you find a specific reason to avoid them. You've given no indication that you have such a reason. Quite the opposite, as you say the system is for internal use where your home-rolled "enhanced" session security is even less important.

It doesn't really matter what you're doing, chances are you will only lessen the security of what PHP already provides for you by trying to roll your own.

Comment: And there was me thinking I was being all clever. I totally see your point but had thought that PHP's built-in sessions weren't that secure.

Answer (score 2):

If they all have their own static IP, store the IP in the session, and compare every time the page loads.  If `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $_SESSION['IP']`, somebody's trying to steal a session.

And don't forget [session_regenerate_id()](http://php.net/session-regenerate-id).

Answer (score 1):

The built-in mechanism should suit your needs. If you insist to roll your own solution, i recommend appending a random piece of data to the end. The best method to generate such random data would be PHP's [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`-function](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes).